# Using a variable inside an object name on python

Tags: python, pyqt

I am wanting to use a variable inside an object name.  To set the Qlabel widget, I would normally do

```
self.label1.setText('label 1')
self.label2.setText('label 2')
```

I'm wanting to use:

```
x = 1
y = 2

self.label(x).setText('label 1')
self.label(y).setText('label 2')
```

I've tried

```
name = ('self.label%d' % x)
name.setText('label 1')

(self.label+str(x)).setText('label 1')
```

I've tried lists as well, but can't seem to get it to work.  Any advice?

Here is full code (using qt Designer, so I import the .ui/.py file:

```
from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore, QtTest
import pandas as pd
import sys

import mainWin



class mainWin(QtGui.QMainWindow,mainWin.Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(self.__class__, self).__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)
        num = len(cat)
        x = 1
        y = 2
        self.drink_label(x).setText('label 1')

def main():
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    form  = mainWin()

    form.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())

if __name__== '__main__':
   main()
```

Comment: How are you creating the labels? Can you show the classes __init__() function?

Comment: I added full code now to original question

Comment: @Jason use [getattr](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#getattr): `getattr(self, "drink_label{}".format(x)).setText('label 1')`

Comment: @eyllanesc that was it!  I kept trying to use the . after self or before the 'drink_label{}'.  Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Probably the best way of doing this is to have a list of Qlabels then access them like this:

```
self.labels[x].setText('label 1')
```

Can also use getattr like this:

```
getattr(self, "label" + x).setText('label 1')
```

Otherwise you could use eval however that isn't really recommended for security issues and makes the code more confusing:

```
eval("self.label(" + x + ").setText('label 2')")
```